$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^n}{1+nx} \stackrel{x \to 1^-}{\sim} -\ln(1-x)$
How to prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^n}{1+nx} \stackrel{x \to 1^-}{\sim} -\ln(1-x)$ ?
First try : I tried to compare the sum with the integral $\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^t}{1+tx}\mathrm{d}t$. But I don't know how to calculate this integral.
Second try :  $\forall x \in [0,1[$, $-\ln(1-x) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}$. So :
\begin{align*}
S(x) - \big(-\ln(1-x)\big) & = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left(\frac{x^n}{1+nx} - \frac{x^n}{n}\right) = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{1+nx} - \frac{1}{n}\right)}_{:=a_n(x)}x^n 
\end{align*}
My aim :  try to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_n(x)x^n \stackrel{x\to1^-}{=} \mathrm{O}(1)$.
We have $$a_n(x) = \frac{n-1-nx}{n(1+nx)} \le \frac{n-nx}{n(1+nx)} = \frac{1-x}{1+nx} \le 1-x$$ thus $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_n(x)x^n \le x \le 1$. But it is not sufficient to prove $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_n(x)x^n = \mathrm{O}(1)$.

Why is it not sufficient to prove that the difference is bounded as $x\to 1^-$? I presume that $f(x)\sim g(x)$ means $f(x)/g(x)\to 1$. If this is indeed the case, then it is enough to show that the difference is $o(-\log(1-x))$.

Sorry I'm not familiar with the notation but how is exactly $\sim$ defined in this context?

@Sounak $f(x) \stackrel{x\to x_0}{\sim} g(x)$ means $\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} =1$.

@SangchulLee $S(x) - \ln(1-x) =O(1)$ means that $S(x)-\ln(1-x)$ is bounded when $x \to 1^-$. But I have only found an upper bound : $S(x) - \ln(1-x) \le 2$.

New Answer. Let $f(x) = -\log(1-x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}$. Then for $x \in (0, 1)$, we have
$$ \frac{f(x)}{x}
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n+1}
\leq S(x)
\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{nx + x}
= \frac{f(x)}{x^2}. $$
Therefore
$$ \frac{1}{x} \leq \frac{S(x)}{f(x)} \leq \frac{1}{x^2} $$
and the desired claim follows by the squeezing lemma.
Addendum. More generally, let $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{x} - 1$ and assume that $\frac{1}{2} < x < 1$ so that $0 < \varepsilon < 1$. Then
\begin{align*}
S(x)
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)x + 1} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-2}}{n + \varepsilon} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n-2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k \varepsilon^k}{n^{k+1}} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{\varepsilon^k}{x^2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n^{k+1}} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{\operatorname{Li}_{k+1}(x)}{x^{k+2}} (1-x)^k \\
&= \frac{-\log(1-x)}{x^2}  - \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x^3}(1-x) + \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{x^4} (1-x)^2 - \cdots,
\end{align*}
where $\operatorname{Li}_s(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n^s}$ is the polylogarithm of order $s$. This allows us to extract the asymptotic expansion of $S(x)$ as $x \to 1^-$ up to any prescribed order.

Old Answer. Here is a simple trick:
\begin{align*}
S(x)
&= S(x) + \frac{\log(1-x)}{x} - \frac{\log(1-x)}{x} \\
&= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{x^n}{1 + nx} - \frac{x^n}{nx} \right) - \frac{\log(1-x)}{x} \\
&= 1 - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{nx(1 + nx)} - \frac{\log(1-x)}{x}.
\end{align*}
Hence, the difference between $S(x)$ and $-\log(1-x)$ is given by
\begin{align*}
S(x) + \log(1-x)
&= \bbox[padding:5px; border:1px dotted navy;]{1 - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{nx(1 + nx)} - \frac{(1-x)\log(1-x)}{x}}.
\end{align*}
However,

The sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{nx(1 + nx)}$ is bounded as $x \to 1^-$, by noting that for $x \in (0, 1)$,
$$ \left| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{nx(1 + nx)} \right|
\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(nx)^2}
= \frac{\zeta(2)}{x^2}. $$

Since $t \log t \to 0$ as $t \to 0^+$, it follows that
$$ \frac{(1-x)\log(1-x)}{x} \to 0 \qquad \text{as}\qquad x \to 1^-. $$


Therefore the difference is bounded as $x \to 1^-$ and we get
$$ S(x) = -\log(1-x) + \mathcal{O}(1). $$

Very impressive.

We can try to get the recipe of the full asymptotics.
Denoting the desired sum as $S$ and changing the order of summation and integration
$$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{1+nx}=\int_0^\infty dt\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^ne^{-t(1+nx)}=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t}}{1-xe^{-tx}}dt$$
Denoting $1-x=\epsilon$
$$S=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t\epsilon}}{e^{t(1-\epsilon)}-(1-\epsilon)}dt\overset{t(1-\epsilon)=s}{=}\frac1{(1-\epsilon)^2}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-\frac{s\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}}}{e^{s-\ln(1-\epsilon)}-1}ds$$
$$=\frac1{(1-\epsilon)^2}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-\frac{(s+\ln(1-\epsilon))\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}}}{e^{s-\ln(1-\epsilon)}-1}ds=e^{-\frac{\epsilon\ln(1-\epsilon)}{1-\epsilon}}\frac1{(1-\epsilon)^2}\int_{-\ln(1-\epsilon)}^\infty e^{-\frac{\epsilon \,t}{1-\epsilon}}\frac{dt}{e^t-1}$$
Integrating by parts
$$=e^{-\frac{\epsilon\ln(1-\epsilon)}{1-\epsilon}}e^{-\frac{\epsilon \,t}{1-\epsilon}}\frac{\ln(1-e^{-t})}{(1-\epsilon)^2}\,\bigg|_{-\ln(1-\epsilon)}^\infty+\frac\epsilon{(1-\epsilon)^3}e^{-\frac{\epsilon \ln(1-\epsilon)}{1-\epsilon}}\int_{-\ln(1-\epsilon)}^\infty e^{-\frac{\epsilon \,t}{1-\epsilon}}\ln(1-e^{-t})dt$$
$$=-\frac{\ln\epsilon}{(1-\epsilon)^2}+\frac\epsilon{(1-\epsilon)^3}e^{-\frac{\epsilon \ln(1-\epsilon)}{1-\epsilon}}\int_{-\ln(1-\epsilon)}^\infty e^{-\frac{\epsilon \,t}{1-\epsilon}}\ln(1-e^{-t})dt$$
The last integrand is dominated by $\,|\ln(1-e^{-t})|$; we can use the DCT to find the limit at $\epsilon\to 0$
Also, decomposing the functions at $\epsilon\to 0$, we can get as many asymptotic terms as we want. For example, the last integral converges at $\epsilon=0$, therefore
$$S=-\ln\epsilon-2\epsilon\ln\epsilon+\epsilon\int_0^\infty\ln(1-e^{-t})dt+O(\epsilon^2\ln\epsilon)=-\ln\epsilon-2\epsilon\ln\epsilon-\frac{\pi^2}6\epsilon+O(\epsilon^2\ln\epsilon)$$

Note that $ - \frac{{\pi ^2 }}{6}\epsilon  = o(\epsilon \ln \epsilon )$.

@Gary, thank you. Correcting.

Thanks for the generalization. I am not sure to understand all the tricky calculations with the integral and  why these manipulations work.
